# Bernoulli number $B_{\frac{p-1}{2}}$

Tags: bernoulli-numbers

There is a prime number $p\equiv1\left(\bmod\,4\right)$ such that the numerator of the Bernoulli number $B_{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ is divisible by $p$?